# How to calculate the remaining amount between two times to get the next time cut down JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have built prayer times using prayertimes.org. Now I need to get the next prayer and how many hours, minutes, seconds remain till the coming prayer. I have converted the date time to 24 formats to be able to get the distances between times and check if the time between two times then the coming prayer is. However, I have not been able to get the correct one.

Prayer time example (Time now is 6:50 - Fajr is 3:05 - Dhuhr is 13 : 10 ... etc)
I have converted time to 24 formate depand on AM or PM.

```
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {


    if (countDownDate > IshaTimeAF && countDownDate <= FajrTimeAF) {
        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = FajrTimeAF - countDownDate;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        document.getElementById("ComingSoon").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        //display = document.querySelector('#ComingSoon') + "UPCOMING PRAYER FAJR";

    }
    else if (countDownDate > FajrTimeAF && countDownDate <= DhuhrTimeAF) {
        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = DhuhrTimeAF - countDownDate;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        document.getElementById("ComingSoon").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        //display = document.querySelector('#ComingSoon') + " UPCOMING PRAYER DHUHR";

    }
    else if (countDownDate > DhuhrTimeAF && countDownDate <= AsrTimeAF) {
        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = AsrTimeAF - countDownDatenow;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        document.getElementById("ComingSoon").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        //  display = document.querySelector('#ComingSoon') + "UPCOMING PRAYER ASR";

    }
    else if (countDownDate > AsrTimeAF && countDownDate <= MaghribTimeAF) {
        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDatenow - MaghribTimeAF;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        document.getElementById("ComingSoon").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        //display = document.querySelector('#ComingSoon') + " UPCOMING PRAYER MAGHRIB";

    }
    else if (countDownDate > MaghribTimeAF && countDownDate <= IshaTimeAF) {
        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - IshaTimeAF;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("ComingSoon").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        //  display = document.querySelector('#ComingSoon') + " UPCOMING PRAYER ISHA";

    }


    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Please don't just post a slew of code - it will put most people off even reading it.  Post a **[mcve]** - a small example to show what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy using a third party library for date-related functions, moment.js is probably exactly what you need.

A combination of `moment().fromNow();` (to work out the remaining time from now until your times) and a custom sort function using `moment().isBefore(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array);` will probably do what you need.

I haven't tested this but something like this should work:

```
var FajrTimeAF = moment({hour: 3, minute: 5})
var DhuhrAF = moment({hour: 13, minute: 10})
var nextTime = moment(FajrTimeAF).isBefore(DhuhrAF) ? FajrTimeAF : DhuhrAF // repeat this check as necessary for other important times
var timeLeft = moment().to(nextTime) // returns remaining time until nextTime
```

Comment: Link to the documentation for further reading: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: as I understand you use isbefore and actually, current time that I will check depend on will be always before and so it will be done.